# How to install external dependencies from my Node.js app?

Tags: node.js, docker, package

I am very new to Node.js. I have created a web app and packaged it using https://github.com/vercel/pkg. The app depends upon Docker Engine and leverages it's API using Docker socket `/var/run/docker.sock`.

```js
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

/* Create Container. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  var Docker = require('dockerode');
  var docker = new Docker({socketPath: '/var/run/docker.sock'});
  docker.createContainer({Image: 'ubuntu', Cmd: ['/bin/bash'], name: 'ubuntu-test'}, function (err, container) {
    res.send("Container created");
  });
});

module.exports = router;
```

I wanted to distribute the app as a standalone executable file with my team. I don't want them to install the external dependencies separately e.g **Docker in this case**.

So **how can I package this docker-engine with my app**? If it can not be packaged how can I install it on a client's machine from my Node.js app?

Answer (score 2):

You've inverted the normal dependency order, breaking the logic used with most apps. Docker is typically the tool that provides all of the dependencies in the image. This avoids the user needing to install Node.js or anything other than docker on their machine. And with everything being a Linux based container there's less of a need to deal with platform specific code.

By inverting the logic, you'll now need to package a platform specific docker installer and require the user has installed and configured Node.JS with any other dependencies on their hosts. That docker installer is non-trivial, tends to require administrative access, and on Windows and Mac involves a VM for the Linux environment. You'll also find the socket name (`/var/run/docker.sock`) may not apply outside of the Linux environment, making the Node.JS app require more customization for each type of docker install.

I'm no aware of any easy way to do this from Node.JS in a platform independent way. Just for installing on Linux, I tend to package an Ansible playbook with multiple roles to perform the install, along with prerequisites, kernel tuning, and settings to trust users with access to the docker engine. Expanding that out to Windows and Mac would require a lot of extra effort, and your users are still required to provide Node.JS on their local machine to do it.

Instead, my advice is to package your Node.JS application as a docker image, so the user only needs to install Docker, which is designed to package other applications.

Comment: Can you provide some brief insights what Kitematic or Docker for Desktop do? Do they also install docker on client's machine? I also have another question, can I isolate the docker enviornment specific to my app only? E.g I don't want users to see the containers using `docker ls` those are created by this the app

Comment: @SkyRar Kitematic is a legacy product that used to be bundled with Docker Desktop. Haven't heard of anyone using that in a long time. I wouldn't base any new solution on that.

Comment: what is your view shipping a static docker daemon https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/binaries?